# Is there a way to edit metadata of videos using Python?

Tags: python, video, metadata, mp4

Is there way to edit metadata of videos via Python? The meta tags I want to edit are 'UserComment' and keywords / tags of the videos or even the title of the video. I've searched for a way to do so but didn't find anything so far.

Comment: You didn't search very well then... About 10 seconds into google I found `mutagen` that seems to be what you're looking for. Alternatively it seems to be common to use `ffmpeg`.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for answering. I've already found 'mutagen' library and unfortunately it doesn't support MP4 videos (from what I've seen in their documentation). ffmpeg seems to be fine in my eyes, I'll try it and will let ya know if it works.